# How to make dictionary keys is one column of Pandas dataframe to the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column containing stringified list containing dictionaries. I was wondering how can I make new columns from these dictionary keys.

I am looking solution using pandas methods like `apply stack etc` and NOT USING FOR LOOP as far as possible.

Here is the problem:

```py
speakers = ['Einstein','Newton']
views = [1000,2000]
ratings0 = ("[{'id': 7, 'name': 'Funny', 'count': 100}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Sad', "
 "'count': 110}, {'id': 9, 'name': 'Happy', 'count': 120}]")

ratings1 = ("[{'id': 7, 'name': 'Happy', 'count': 200}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Funny', "
 "'count': 210}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Sad', 'count': 220}]")


ratings = [ratings0, ratings1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'speaker': speakers, 'ratings': ratings,'views':views})

print(df)
speaker                                            ratings  views
0  Einstein  [{'id': 7, 'name': 'Funny', 'count': 100}, {'i...   1000
1    Newton  [{'id': 7, 'name': 'Happy', 'count': 200}, {'i...   2000
```

My attempt so far,

```py
# new dataframe only for ratings
dfr = df['ratings'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
dfr = dfr.apply(pd.DataFrame)
dfr = dfr.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='name'))
dfr = dfr.apply(pd.DataFrame.stack)

print(dfr)

 0               1               2          
  count id   name count id   name count id   name
0   100  7  Funny   110  1    Sad   120  9  Happy
1   200  7  Happy   210  3  Funny   220  2    Sad
```

This gives multi-index dataframe. I tried sorting the dictionary, but still it is not sorted and the column `name` does not have the same values. Also, I am unsure how to move the values of column `name` to replace column `count` and remove other unwanted columns.

### Final Wanted Solution

```
speaker   views Funny Sad Happy
Einstein  1000 100   110 120  
Newton    2000 210   220 200
```

### Update

I am  using Pandas 0.20 and the method `.explode()` is absent in my workplace and I am not permitted to update Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sum`, `index.repeat` to construct a new dataframe and join it `df[['speaker', 'views']]` and assign it to `df1`. Next, `set_index`, `unstack`, and `reset_index`

```
df['ratings'] = df['ratings'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(df.ratings.sum(), index=df.index.repeat(df.ratings.str.len()))
                   .drop('id', 1).join(df[['speaker', 'views']]))
df1.set_index(['speaker', 'views', 'name'])['count'].unstack().reset_index()

Out[213]:
name   speaker  views  Funny  Happy  Sad
0     Einstein  1000   100    120    110
1     Newton    2000   210    200    220
```

---

**Note**: `name` in the final output is the label of the columns axis. If you don't want to see it, just chain additional `rename_axis` as follows

```
df1.set_index(['speaker', 'views', 'name'])['count'].unstack().reset_index() \
                                                    .rename_axis([None], axis=1)

Out[214]:
    speaker  views  Funny  Happy  Sad
0  Einstein  1000   100    120    110
1  Newton    2000   210    200    220
```

Answer (score 4):

For `pandas >= 0.25.0` you can use `ast.literal_eval` + `explode` + `pivot`

```
ii = df.set_index('speaker')['ratings'].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode()

u = pd.DataFrame(ii.tolist(), index=ii.index).reset_index()

u.pivot('speaker', 'name', 'count')
```

```
name      Funny  Happy  Sad
speaker
Einstein    100    120  110
Newton      210    200  220
```

---

For older versions of `pandas`

```
a = df['speaker']
b = df['ratings']

ii = [
  {**{'speaker': name}, **row}
  for name, element in zip(a, b) for row in ast.literal_eval(element)
]

pd.DataFrame(ii).pivot('speaker', 'name', 'count')
```

Comment: I am using pandas 0.20 and unfortunately can not update pandas and use .explode.

Comment: @astro123 posted a version for older versions of `pandas`, it might even be faster than the first

Comment: Thanks, this saved my rest of the day, I have been trying this question from 10am to almost 3pm.

Comment: What can we do if we have one more column `views = [1000,2000]` ? Sorry I could not make it work.

Comment: Include it in the `zip`, and make the first dictionary `{'speaker': name, 'views': view}`.  You might need to use `pivot_table` with multiple `index` columns

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions, I will definitely take a look.

Answer (score 0):

For loops are not always bad. You can give it a try:

```py
dfr = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','name','count'])

for i in range(len(df)):
    x = pd.DataFrame(df['ratings'].apply(ast.literal_eval)[i])
    x.index = [i]*len(x)
    dfr = dfr.append(x)


dfr = dfr.reset_index()   
dfr = (dfr.drop('id',axis=1)
         .pivot_table(index=['index'], columns='name',
                      values='count',aggfunc='sum')
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index())

df_final = df.join(dfr)
df_final.drop(['index','ratings'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df_final
```

Gives:

```py
    speaker  views  Funny  Happy  Sad
0  Einstein   1000    100    120  110
1    Newton   2000    210    200  220
```